# "No callbacks found" error message in magento 2 cron job

Tags: magento2, cron, magento2.2.3, crontab

I have created a crontab in my custom module and scheduled at every 10 minutes.
It is working fine, when I am running the "php bin/magento setup:upgrade" command.

So, first time it is working fine, in cron_schedule table, status = success and message = null. which is fine. but, after 10 minutes this cron is not working.

Having **status = error** and **message = "No callbacks found"**. 
I have debugged the code and found that in second time cron **"instance"** is not being set.

Can anyone help me on this? Why there is no instance in second time?

Thank you.

Here is my crontab.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
<group id="index">
    <job name="cron_setup_job" instance="Vendor\Module\Cron\ClassName" method="execute">
        <schedule>*/10 * * * *</schedule>
    </job>
</group>
</config>
```

Comment: can you add your code?

Comment: I have added my code in the question, please review it.

Comment: Your cron schedule expression is wrong. To execute every 10 minutes, use `*/10 * * * *` as schedule value. With your expression it will execute every 0 minutes, means every hour

Comment: @JaiminSutariya Sorry, Initially it was "*/10 * * * *", but after that I have changed it to 1 hour. As per my question I have updated my cron schedule.

Comment: If it executes first time successfully, it should execute the second time. If you can provide your error log, it will be helpful to debug the issue.

Comment: Here is the log of exception.log file.

[2018-12-11 05:00:09] main.CRITICAL: No callbacks found {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): No callbacks found at vendor/magento/module-cron/Observer/ProcessCronQueueObserver.php:278)"} []

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, My cron job is working fine. I don't know what was the issue with my crontab.xml and cron class file. But, I have deleted my files and copied and pasted core module's files in my module and renamed them. This time I have changed job name, and it is working fine for me. Now, I don't have "No callbacks found" error anymore. If anyone has such error/issue, advice to use core module's crontab.xml file in your module and do needful changes. It will work fine.
Most Important: Need to set `<group id="default">`
Thanks.